# directive twoway data binding inside ng-repeat is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, prototypal-inheritance

Here i want to update controller scope value as per change in directive scope but **its only working outside the ng-repeat** and **its not working inside ng-repeat..**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      <h3>
    outside repeat
    </h3>
      <br> Name <strong>{{name}}</strong>
      <div class="directive" my-directive name="name"></div>
      <button ng-click="run()">See changes</button>

      <br>
      <br>
      <h3>
    Inside repeat
    </h3>
      <br>
      <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in rawdata">
        {{k}} {{v.key}} Name <strong>{{name}}</strong>
        <div class="directive" my-directive name="name"></div>
        <button ng-click="run()">See changes</button>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.name = "HappyNewYear2016";
      $scope.run = function() {
        alert($scope.name);
      }

      $scope.rawdata = [{
        key: "event1",
      }, {
        key: "event2",
      }];

    });

    app.directive("myDirective", function() {

      return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {
          name: "="
        },
        template: [
          "<div>",
          "Name : <strong>{{name}}</strong>;  Change name:<input type='text' ng-model='name' /><br/>",
        ].join("")
      };
    });
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/BijayRai/pJLT8/696/)

Please help me in updating controller value from directive inside this ngrepeat..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the problem is the `$scope.name` inside the controller is not the same as you are passing to directive inside the `ng-repeat` element, because `ng-repeat` does create a child scope which is prototypically inherited from the parent scope while looping through `rawdata` object.

---

There are several ways to solve this problem.

1. If you wanted to solved this child and parent scope related issue just by using `$parent` annotation before `name` which will refers to parent scope.

[**Plunkr**](http://jsfiddle.net/jpx67dLo/2/) With $parent in directive

**Cons:-**

But after certain point `$parent` will make you crazy. Like suppose if you have two or three hierarchy of child scope it will become like `$parent.$parent.$parent.name` which looks very wiered.

---

2. In your case `name` is of primitive datatype, so while creating child scope the primitive datatypes values of parent scope aren't accessible inside the child scope. That is the reason why you were using `$parent` to indicates that name belongs to parent scope. You could overcome this problem just by following  `do annotation` while declaring object. Which will help you to make parent scope property available inside the child by following prototypal inheritance.

**HTML**

```
<div class="directive" my-directive name="model.name"></div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.model = {
    name: 'HappyNewYear2016'
};
```

[**Plunkr**](http://jsfiddle.net/jpx67dLo/3/) with Dot Notation

---

3. You could solve this problem just by passing `name` value from the `run` function on `ng-click="run(name)"`

**Html**

```
<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in rawdata">
    {{k}} {{v.key}} Name <strong>{{name}}</strong>
    <div class="directive" my-directive name="name"></div>
    <button ng-click="run(name)">See changes</button>
    <br>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.run = function(name) {
    alert(name);
}
```

---

4. You could use controllerAs syntax while declaring controller with its alias and the pass the controller `name` property by its alias.

[**Working Plunkr**](http://jsfiddle.net/jpx67dLo/)

Comment: Thankyou so much @Pankaj .. doing annotation solves my problem.. :) :) Once again Thank you so much for all the explanation and working plunkr..

Comment: Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's all because of how prototypical inheritance works as both scopes directive and controller have same name for model. Child directive shadows the controller model.

Instead of storing controller model directly as variable use it with object.

```
$scope.data = {
  name : 'HappyNewYear2016'
}
```

Then use it as`data.name` to setup in ng-repeat. It will reflect it in parent as well.